# how to join table in laravel

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I have 2 tables
lets say the 1st one have something like id_teacher_a, id_teacher_b

the 2nd table have the detailed information from table 1 (teacher name, teacher address, etc)

i want to show only the teacher name, so how to join them?

my controller

```
$data['getid'] = Classroom::select(
        'classroom.id',
        'teacher.id as tchr_id',
        'teacher.name as tchr_name'
      )
      ->join('teacher', 'classroom.teacher_id', '=', 'teacher.id')
      ->first();
```

when i want to show table of classroom it would be like

```
#classroom id   #teacher_name_a   #teacher_name_b
1                a                 b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work just fine:

```
DB::table('classrooms')
    ->join('teacher as ta', 'ta.id', '=', 'classrooms.id_teacher_a')
    ->join('teacher as tb', 'tb.id', '=', 'classrooms.id_teacher_b')
    ->select([
        'classrooms.id as classroom_id',
        'ta.name as teacher_name_a'
        'tb.name as teacher_name_b'
    ])->get();
```

Alternatively if you have the following to your Classroom model:

```
class Teacher extends Model
{
    public function teacherA()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo(Teacher::class, 'id_teacher_a');
    }

    public function teacherB()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo(Teacher::class, 'id_teacher_b');
    }
}
```

Then you can also do:

```
 Classroom::query()
          ->with(['teacherA', 'teacherB'])
          ->map(function ($classroom) {
              return [
                  'classroom id' => $classroom->id,
                  'teacher_name_a' => $classroom->teacherA->name,
                  'teacher_name_b' => $classroom->teacherB->name
              ];
          });
```